# Should we change the availability date when we resubmit the app in to App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode5, appstore-approval

Last month(15-Feb-14) I have uploaded an app in to App Store with availability date 20-Feb-14 and my app status was "Waiting For Review". Yesterday(1-Mar-14) I got one issue and again I had to resubmit the app in to App Store and my app status is "Waiting For Review". My question is Should we change the availability date when we resubmit the app?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Better ask on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would change it to release when ready, unless you wish to specify a new date.

Answer (score 1):

No, the availability determines when the app will be available. If the date is in the past, it means that the app will be visible on the AppStore.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can u provide some links?

Comment: [This link](http://www.pixelenvision.com/3204/itunes-connect-availability-date-vs-release-date-explained/) explains how the availability date works

Answer (score 0):

With more explanation... There's no need to manage an availability date and it is separate than the review submission process and only is considered once approval is granted for the app to be sold.

If your date is in the future, it will sit and wait to go on sale when that future data arrives.

If your date is in the past, it will go on sale as soon as approval is processed and the store can update the database.